# how to get TexShop to auto-complete custom citation and cross-reference commands

Tags: citing, texshop, auto-completion, bibdesk

I'd like to use a custom cross-referencing command, called `\pref{}`, in TexShop and have it trigger autocompletion the way `\ref{}` does. Similarly for a custom citation command `\citepage{}`.

I have the working commands. Citation completion with `\cite` via Bibdesk also works. I just want TexShop to show me labels when I type `\pref{labelname-ESC`, and citation options when typing `\citpage{bibkey-ESC`, i.e. treat them like `\ref{` and `\cite{` respectively.

Is there a preference list of commands that trigger these special completions somewhere, that I can edit?

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible without modifying the code and recompiling TeXShop, specifically in the `TSTextView` object. It's not hard, but would require some familiarity with Objective-C. If you use `\citepage{` as a command name, it should work as-is.